# Aurelia app location in a subfolder

Tags: aurelia

```
<div aurelia-app>
    <script src="~/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
    </script>
</div>
```

The above works perfectly well, but when I try to make `aurelia-app="/js/aurelia/app"` I get a console error.

```
Error:
TypeError: m.configure is not a function
```

Comes from this line in es6.promise.js:

```
 if (handler) {
                if (!ok)
                  record.h = true;
                result = handler === true ? value : handler(value);
    result = handler === true ? value : handler(value);
```

Not sure what to change below to make it work:

```
<div aurelia-app="/js/aurelia/app">
    <script src="~/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might need you to post a bit more information about the structure of your app but try the following in your `config.js`:

```
  paths: {
    "*": "js/aurelia/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  }
```

And:

```
  <div aurelia-app>
    <script src="~/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: That did it but I am curious to why that would work but `aurelia-app="/js/aurelia/app"` doesn't.